# Grails - Spring Security - Many dynamic roles

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm developing an application using Grails and Spring Security.

My wish is, when the user creates his account informing his company name, the app creates an entry in the company, role and user tables and relates that role and user with the company entry.

The role created will be like an administrator which has permission for do every thing. This user with that role can creates new roles specifying the permissions but all roles created should be only in the company scope, so those roles should not be available for users of others companies.

I've seen that the Spring Security has a feature called Requestmap which for each URL, the application can specify the roles which will have access.

I don't know if this is the best solution, because in my app the number of roles will increase at least as many as the number of user.

Do you guys have some advice of how to solve this problem?

Thank you for all.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [Spring Security ACL plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-acl/v3/index.html).

With this plugin you would be able to add permissions (like write or read permission) to certain users on certain domain models.

Have a look on example taken from documentation:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#report, write) or " +
             "hasPermission(#report, admin)")
Report updateReport(Report report, params) {
   report.properties = params
   report.save()
   report
}
```

By using `PreAuthorize` annotation it is checked if user has write (or admin) permission on this certain `Report`  entity.